# Distance between points of different layer

Tags: qgis, distance

I would like to get the blue points that are less than a certain distance from the green points (for example 2 meters). Green and blue points belong to different layers.

How can I select and export all the data of the blue points to a new layer that are no more than 2 meters away from a green point using QGIS?

[image: blue points and red points on separate layers]

Comment: I want to select and export to a new layer all the data of the blue points that are no more than 2 meters away from a green point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select (or extract) by expression:

`overlay_nearest( layer:='green_point', max_distance:=2)`

Then right-click the layer Export - Save selected features

[image]